# will I be charged by aws s3, if I create a post then delete it through admin?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using django and elastic beanstalk. I just made a new post and saw I was charged 0.01$ from aws which kinda worries me. Does this mean every time I make a post this amount will be charged? what if I make one then delete it, will I still be charged? can someone with an experience of elastic beanstalk help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not delete it and see what happens to the cost? Deleting doesn't account for data transfer thus my guess is you won't pay a thing. Putting items on the queue does account for data transfer and you will pay. Keeping items on the queue (data storage) will cost you as you can see here: https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/pricing/

> Amazon EC2 Pricing (includes pricing for instances, load balancing, elastic block storage, and data transfer)
>
> Amazon S3 Pricing (includes pricing for storage and data transfer)

Comment: I was about to try this if I don't get any answer, so if I create one and delete one through admin I don't get charged eh do you have an experience with aws s3?

Comment: You will still be charged for the data transfer IN. I've worked with S3 and EC2, but not with Elastic Beanstalk. One more experiment you can try is to put a file on the queue, wait an hour and 1 minute and see that you have been billed for data storage.

Comment: ok thanks for the advice, it's my first time so I'm still confused. How much does S3 charge usually?sorry this question is so vague but they charged me 0.01$ for one post....

Comment: It's normal, don't worry about the confusion. It's hard to manage AWS costs at scale and it might be daunting for a new user.

https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/ you can see that you have a free tier and I don't know if you've hit those limits: 

> As part of the AWS Free Usage Tier, you can get started with Amazon S3 for free. Upon sign-up, new AWS customers receive 5 GB of Amazon S3 standard storage, 20,000 Get Requests, 2,000 Put Requests, and 15GB of data transfer out each month for one year.

Comment: thanks, yeah it's kinda daunting to me. I didn't even do any thing and they charged me. I have a few more questions about aws, but couldn't really get any answer, do you mind checking another post about this stuff?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110896/is-it-possible-to-deploy-a-project-without-apache-config-file-and-i-set-debug-f

Answer (score 1):

The actual issue here seems to be a misunderstanding of the terminology used in pricing.

S3 charges $0.005 **per 1,000** PUT/POST/LIST requests (some regions are somewhat higher, but this pricing is used through the rest of the answer).

This terminology **does not mean** that each request will actually be billed as $0.005 ÷ 1000 = $0.000005, even though this is a close approximation of what they will ultimately cost.

It actually means you are billed `CEIL(TOTAL_REQUESTS / 1000) * $0.005`...

...where `TOTAL_REQUESTS` is the number of that type of request you made during a monthly billing interval within one S3 region.

So making 1, 2, 500, 999, or 1000 requests is still a total monthly usage of $0.005, rounded up to $0.01.  Not $0.01 each.

Making 1001 through 2000 total requests is a total of $0.005 + $0.005 = $0.01.

Making 2001 through 3000 total requests is a total of $0.015, which rounds up to $0.02.

*...ad infinitum...*

You wouldn't billed more than $0.01 *total* until after the first 2000 requests.